# How to swap two custom cells with one another in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swap

I have implemented two custom cells in the tableview.Now I want to replace these two  custom cells with one another. How to achieve this?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0):

Implement following tableview methods and write your code in it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
// return boolean value for a specific or all cells, you want to enable movement
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
// Handle array element movement along with your row/cell
}
```

Share your full source code better help

Comment: I want to swap these custom cell automatically .. Not by the user itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to reorder rows in `UITableView`. Take a look at two delegates that are implemented in the `UITableView`.

They are: `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` and `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`.

Also take a look at [tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/reordering-rows-table-view-ios8-swift) that show how it is possible to implement.

Comment: By using this method user can swap the cells but i want that it will swap automactically..  I have two cell just want to replace with one another.Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Along with tableview delegates, use `moveRow(at: <IndexPath>, to: <IndexPath>)`, to move your row programatically (automatically), without user interaction.

```
tblTabel.moveRow(at: <IndexPath>, to: <IndexPath>)    


// Tableview Delegates

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
  // return boolean value for a specific or all cells, you want to enable movement
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
  // Handle array element movement along with your row/cell
}
```